# Failing to add a gradient to a UIImageView in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

In a `UICollectionViewCell` i'm adding a gradient to a `UIImageView` like this:

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if thumbnailImageView.layer.sublayers?.first == nil {
            thumbnailImageView.addGradient(firstColor: .clear, secondColor: .black)
        }
    }
```

I want to do the same but in a `UIViewController`, so far I could only make it work on `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if thumbnailImageView.layer.sublayers?.first == nil {
        thumbnailImageView.addGradient(firstColor: .clear, secondColor: .black)
    }
}
```

I want to the `UIImageView` to have the gradient as soon as it appears like I did in `UICollectionView`. Do you know how can I do this?

```
extension UIView{

    func addGradient(firstColor: UIColor, secondColor: UIColor){
        clipsToBounds = true
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code, which worked for `UIViewController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: In which method of the UIViewController?

Comment: In ViewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: I also have to remove the if statement, or it won't work.